# Замена проекта в eclipse под андроид

Tags: android, eclipse

Выложил платное приложение на плэймаркет, сделал в этом же проекте некоторые изменения, поменял название проекта, поменял package name, и собрался выложить и это приложение,но уже как бесплатную версию. Удалив с планшета старую версию,установил на него уже новый apk,и зайдя в плэймаркет на страницу своего платного приложения увидел что оно у меня уже установлено, то есть то, что я поменял имя пакета и название проекта не помешало плэймаркету определить что это то же самое приложение. Суть вопроса в том,что нужно с обрезанной бесплатной версии приложения переходить по ссылки на страницу скачки платной полной версии, и устанавливать новую,как совсем другое приложение. Неужели надо создавать два разных проекта?

Comment: А как вы **package name** меняли? Через **Android Tools**?

Comment: Щелкнул правой кнопкой по имени пакета и изменил имя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя пакета надо менять через **Android Tools** (правой кнопкой на проекте надо нажать и там выбрать). Так вы измените имя пакета приложения, по коему маркет определяет приложение. **Android Tools** также изменит имя пакета приложения в манифесте.